# Exclude URLs from Django REST Swagger

Tags: python, django, rest, swagger

I have a few URLs that I want to exclude from my REST API documentation. I'm using Django REST Swagger and the only documentation I can find (https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) doesn't really tell me much. There is the "exclude_namespaces" part of SWAGGER_SETTINGS in settings.py, but there is no real explanation or example of how to use this.

Simply put, I want to exclude any URLs from the docs that start with the following:

```
/api/jobs/status/
/api/jobs/parameters/
```

How could I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help offered :P

Comment: I have a somewhat related but a more fine-grained question on excluding specific HTTP methods for specific endpoints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813253/exclude-swagger-docs-for-specific-http-methods

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the namespaces to exclude are the one defined in your urls.py.

So for example, in your case:

urls.py:

```
internal_apis = patterns('',
                     url(r'^/api/jobs/status/',...),
                     url(r'^/api/jobs/parameters/',...),
                     )

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + patterns('',
              url(r'^', include(internal_apis, namespace="internal_apis")),
              ...
              )
```

and in your settings.py:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "exclude_namespaces": ["internal_apis"],    #  List URL namespaces to ignore
}
```

This is well described [in there](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/64)

Comment: This is no longer works in the latest version of django

Answer (score 19):

For all of those who found the above answer not helpful:
I guess that "exclude_namespaces" doesn't work anymore in new versions of django swagger. I had almost the same problem (I didnt't want to show my internal apis in documentation) and the above solution didn't work for me. I've been searching for like an hour for a solution and finally found something helpful.

There are some attributes that you can pass to **SchemaGenerator**. One of them is **urlconf**. You can set it to be "yourproject.api.urls" and it will get only urls defined there! Of course, you have to make sure that all the urls that you want to exclude from your api documentation are not included there.

I hope that at least one person found my answer helpful ;).

A problem comes when you want to have many urls.py included in your api documentation. I don't know what should be done then. If anyone comes up with an answer to this new problem - feel free to comment my answer. thanks!

Comment: You can also disable a specific view by adding `schema = None` to its attributes.

Answer (score 8):

With new version of django swagger, we don't need to create view to exclude some urls. Below code will disable test2 url.

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
urlpatterns1 = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^test/', include('test.urls')),
    url(r'^test1/', Test2.as_view()),
]

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='API Documentation', patterns=urlpatterns1)

urlpatterns = urlpatterns1 + [
    url(r'^docs/', schema_view),
    url(r'^test2/', Test2.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 6):

Ola's answer is correct. `exclude_namespaces` is no longer supported.

For finer control of the documentation, create your own schema view by using a function-based or class-based view. This can be useful if you want to produce documentation for specific URL patterns, or URL confs.

In your `views.py`, you can do the following:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.schemas import SchemaGenerator
from rest_framework_swagger import renderers

class SwaggerSchemaView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [
        renderers.OpenAPIRenderer,
        renderers.SwaggerUIRenderer
    ]

    def get(self, request):
        generator = SchemaGenerator(title='Your API Documentation', urlconf='your_app.urls')
        schema = generator.get_schema(request=request)

    return Response(schema)
```

The above will only render documentation for the URLs that are specified in the `urlconf` argument of the `SchemaGenerator`. Also, don't forget to set up your `urls.py` as well:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from views import SwaggerSchemaView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/docs/$', SwaggerSchemaView.as_view(), name='docs'),
]
```

Comment: This answer looks as if it might well address I problem I have, but I'm not sure what is meant by the `urlconf='your_app.urls'` - would you mind expanding on that, please?

Comment: @knirirr it is the path to the urls.py file that corresponds to whatever URLs you want to generate the Swagger Schema View for. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. All the API URLs are in a main urls.py file but I only need some of them to be displayed in the Swagger documentation. If Django can handle two files then I could presumably put those which are actually to be documented in a separate file, leaving the private ones in the main URL file.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I did, except I created a new urls.py file for the private ones.

Answer (score 4):

For the newest version of drf-swagger you can defile url patterns in the schema generator.

For example:

    `url_patterns = (
        url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls, namespace='api')),
    )
    generator = schemas.SchemaGenerator(title='Core API', patterns=url_patterns)`

Answer (score 3):

A more flexible solution would be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('user.urls', namespace="user")),
    path('locations/', include('location.urls')),
    path('departments/', include('department.urls', namespace="department")),
    path('my_secret_api/', include('secret.urls', namespace="secret_api")),
]

to_exclude = ['secret_api',] # some more namespaces here
swagger_urls = [item for item in urlpatterns if hasattr(item,"namespace") and item.namespace not in to_exclude]
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Highky', patterns=swagger_urls)
urlpatterns += [
        path('api/docs/', schema_view),
]
```

`urlpatterns` will have all five paths, but `swagger_urls` will have four paths excluding `secret_api`.

All of your URLs and includes will continue to work as they were, except we are now passing our modified `urlpatterns` that we want to show in the Swagger docs. The checks will also cover the include where you don't specify a namespace (like in our case, where the namespace is not defined in the location).

Answer (score 1):

#### views.py

any view class

```
class ...ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ....objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = ...Serializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete'] # add or exclude
```

any function-based view

```
@api_view(['get']) # target field
def function(request):
    ...
    return Response(...)
```