# How to hide Some API in django rest swagger?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have to API end point one is product and another is price, I want to hide price API from swagger documentation. How will I achieve this?

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^v1/products', include('project.products.v1.product_urls')),
url(r'^v1/price', include('project.products.v1.price_urls')), ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude URLs from Django REST Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263696/exclude-urls-from-django-rest-swagger)

Comment: 'exclude_namespaces' : ['V1'] ,not working

Answer (score 7):

use  swagger_schema = None, order to exclude the view from schema generation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more elaborate answer for your query.

So in views.py file you must add a decorator above your function in the below form.

```
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema 
@swagger_auto_schema(auto_schema=None) 
def get(self, request): 
    pass
```

and you are about to go.

i hope it helps everyone.